# How to render custom view mode in d7

Tags: routes, theming, entities

I'm trying to render nodes with a custom view mode, having another tab for each node in the same place than "Edit", "View", etc. So I have declared my custom view mode with hook_entity_info_alter, my new "tab" with hook_menu, with a page_callback pointing to a custom function that should return the node according to my custom view node. 
It works great, but the node title is rendered too. How can I remove the node title ?
Here is the code. Thanks!

```
   /**
   * Implements hook_entity_info_alter().
   */
   function test_custom_view_mode_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
     $entity_info['node']['view modes']['another_teaser'] = array(
       'label' => t('Another teaser'),
       'custom settings' => TRUE,
     );
   }

   /**
   * Implements hook_menu().
   */
   function test_custom_view_mode_menu()
   {      $items['node/%node/another-teaser'] = array(
           'title' => 'Another Teaser',
           'page callback' => '_test_custom_view_mode_display_content',
           'page arguments' => array(1),
           'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
           'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
       );   

          return $items;
   }
   /**
   * Custom page callback hook_menu().
   */

   function _test_custom_view_mode_display_content($node) {
     $node_viewed = node_view(node_load($node->nid), 'another_teaser');

     return array(
              'content' => array(
                'node' => $node_viewed,
              ),
            );
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the node title and not the page title (i.e. from page.tpl.php) that's showing?

Comment: Thanks Clive ! I didn't thought about it.
I just add to template_preprocess_node this code snippet:
  `if($vars['view_mode'] == 'another_teaser') {
    $vars['title'] = '';
  }`

Comment: Variable name $node_rendered is misleading as it has not actually been rendered at this point. Better would be $node_view or $node_render_array or something like that.

Comment: you're right, I changed it

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to render send the element as html out put since there is no any theme function defined. See how this output process [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7).

So your return array should be:

```
 return array(
          '#markup' => $node_rendered
        );
```