# hook_menu() to display node view mode

Tags: 7, routes

How to create hook_menu to display node view mode?

node/% - full view mode (default)

node/%/subpage - custom created view mode of this node, for example "subpage"

I've tried this: [How to render custom view mode in d7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78478/how-to-render-custom-view-mode-in-d7) but it doesn't work. Maybe something is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module exists that does just that: [View Mode Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_page).

Check it out and [inspect the source](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/view_mode_page/tree/view_mode_page.module) to see how it works.